# Printing result of a bitwise XOR in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, xor

When I am trying to do a bitwise XOR of two strings, I get x��K or similar output. The code I am using:

```
char test[] = "teststring";
char test2[] = "testtwostring";
char *bytearray = NULL;
bytearray = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(test2)+1));

for(int j=0; (j< strlen(test) && j< strlen(test2)); j++){
    bytearray[j] += test[j] ^ test2[j];
}

printf(bytearray)
```

Should it not save the XOR result of both string, in each of the bytearray elements, and then print out a new result string? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Do not use your printable data as a `printf()` format string.  Always use an explicit format.

Comment: How exactly do you want it to be output? As hex?

Answer (score 4):

There are many problems in your code:

- `bytearray[j] += test[j] ^ test2[j];` modifies `bytearray`, but it is uninitialized, so its values should not even be read at all and whatever they are is unpredictable. This completely explains your observations.
- you do not null terminate the string in `bytearray`, so printing it invokes undefined behavior as it is uninitialized.
- you pass `printf` the byte array directly. If by coincidence it contains a `%` character, that would invoke undefined behavior as you do not pass any extra arguments to `printf`.  You should at least write `printf("%s\n", bytearray);`
- The values in `bytearray` are not necessarily printable characters.
- calling `strlen(test)` and `strlen(test2)` in the test expression is very inefficient as this operation is expensive and gets repeated for each iteration of the loop.  Use this test instead:

  ```
  for (j = 0; test[j] != '\0' && test2[j] != '\0'; j++) {
      ...
  ```

Since your goal is to *save the XOR result of both strings*, you should modify the code this way:

```
char test[] = "teststring";
char test2[] = "testtwostring";
size_t len = strlen(test);
size_t len2 = strlen(test2);
unsigned char *bytearray = malloc(len2 + 1);
size_t j;

for (j = 0; j < len && j < len2; j++) {
    bytearray[j] = test[j] ^ test2[j];
}
for (; j < len2; j++) {
    bytearray[j] = test2[j];
}

printf("XOR byte values: \n");
for (j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
    printf("%02X ", bytearray[j]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: And the for loop termination is `(j< strlen(test) && j< strlen(test2))` but the `malloc` is for the strlen of test2 only. bytearray should be set to the greater length of test and test2.

Comment: @dawg: it is unclear why the OP does that, but since the loop stops at the shortest of both strings, this is not a real problem. `bytearray` may just be too long.

Comment: `strlen()` in virtually all modern compilers is an intrinsic function. If the length of a string can be determined at compile time it usually is (provided you include the appropriate header).

Comment: @dreamlax: The shrewdness of modern compilers should not prevent newbie programmers from learning some basic skills.  It the present case, it takes extra insight for the compiler to determine that neither of the strings gets modified inside the loop. It is still doable here, but not in most non trivial code.

Comment: @chqrlie: One should code for readability first and foremost. After all, programming languages are there for the convenience of the programmer, not the computer.

Comment: @dreamlax: I agree readability is king, but clarity is even more important: if you claim `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)` is more readable, I'm afraid you are in the wrong place.  This idiom begs for a rewrite and calls for an intense scrutiny to determine if `s` is modified in the loop or not. What is less readable in `for (size_t i = 0, len = strlen(s); i < len; i++)` ?

Comment: @chqrlie: If `s` shouldn't be changed, it should be declared `const` anyway. If the loop body is so large you can't tell whether `s` is being modified, you have other readability problems.

Comment: @dreamlax: declaring `s` as `const char *` gives the compiler no guarantee that the string it points to does not get modified via an alias. There will be many cases where I can tell and the compiler cannot. I have also seen many cases where the programmer though he could tell and was wrong.

Comment: Suggest `char *bytearray` --> `unsigned char *bytearray`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized `bytearray`, so it contains whatever garbage happened to be in that section of memory when it was allocated. You want to do:

```
memset(bytearray, 0, sizeof(char) * (strlen(test2) + 1));
```

after you allocate the array with `malloc()`. As @John Bollinger noted, you can combine the `malloc` and `memset` by calling `calloc`:

```
bytearray = calloc(strlen(test2) + 1, sizeof(char));
```

As another alternative, you could just assign instead of adding:

```
bytearray[j] = test[j] ^ test2[j];
```

instead of:

```
bytearray[j] += test[j] ^ test2[j];
```

Also, you shouldn't call `strlen` repeatedly, since the value will never change. You should just call it once each for `test` and `test2`, store those values in variables, and use the variables. Right now `strlen` is getting unnecessarily called twice each time your `for` loop iterates.

Comment: Or use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.